# jquery each element id

Tags: jquery, each

For some reason its only finding one div instead of finding all divs with that id.

JS:

```
jQuery('#showoffline').click(function(){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('#offlineestreams'),function(){
        jQuery(this).css("display","block");
    });
});
```

Divs are something like this:

```
<div id="offlineestreams" style="display = none;">
Something here
</div>
<div id="offlineestreams" style="display = none;">
Something here2
</div>
```

But only the first one shows :\ Why is that happening?

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: ID's are unique, so jQuery assumes there is only element with that ID, as anything else would be invalid markup

Comment: use `class="offlinestreams"` instead and `jQuery('.showoffline').click` to select `class`

Comment: To add to Jason and adeneo's comments - use `class` rather than `id`

Comment: oh didn't check comments, lol

Comment: Given the constant stream of questions that feature duplicate `id`s on elements, is there a tutorial somewhere that fails to mention the invalid nature of duplicating `id`s? I'm beginning to think it'd be faster to email each, and every, website that 'teaches' HTML *without* (apparently) mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` must be unique, You have duplicated the id `offlinestrams`. An alternate solution would be add a `class` to the `divs` which you are going to group. try some thing like below,

### HTML

```
<div class="offlineestreams">
    Something here
</div>
<div class="offlineestreams">
    Something here2
</div>
```

### JQUERY

```
jQuery('#showoffline').click(function(){
     jQuery(".offlinestream").hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VN6dH/)

Comment: Is there any way I could make something like this work: `code`  if(jQuery(this).css("display","none")){
   jQuery(this).css("display","block");
  }
  if(jQuery(this).css("display","block")){
   jQuery(this).css("display","none");
  }

Answer (score 0):

`ids` must be unique, i am pretty sure `jQuery('#offlineestreams')` will only return 1 object. you should be using classes

Comment: You can be certain rather than pretty sure. A selector using an id only ever returns one element.

Comment: @MattBurland: Depends on the browser, actually.  (And possibly the jQuery version.)  I've seen it return the first element as well as all elements.  Either way, it's undefined behavior, so even in a browser where it works it isn't *guaranteed* to work and can change at any time.

Comment: @David: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) docs clearly say `Selects a single element with the given id attribute.` and that it maps to `document.getElementById`. But it's certainly not something anybody should rely on.

Answer (score 0):

id's should be unique. Try adding a class to the divs you want eg:

```
<div id="offlinestreams1" class="offlinestreams" style="display = none;">
Something here
</div>
<div id="offlinestreams2" class="offlinestreams" style="display = none;">
Something else here
</div>
```

and then your script could be:

```
jQuery('#showoffline').click(function(){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('.offlineestreams'),function(){
        jQuery(this).css("display","block");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since element `id`s are required to be unique, this behavior is undefined and browser-specific.  Sometimes you might get one result, sometimes all, perhaps sometimes even none.

Use a `class` instead of an `id`, or make the `id`s unique.

```
<div class="offlineestreams" style="display = none;">
    Something here
</div>
<div class="offlineestreams" style="display = none;">
    Something here2
</div>
```

and...

```
jQuery('.offlineestreams') ...
```

Additionally, any time you experience unexpected behavior in rendering, DOM element selection/traversal, etc. a very useful first step would be to [validate the markup](http://validator.w3.org).  If the markup is invalid, you'll want to fix it before trying to debug the issue regarding that markup.

Answer (score 0):

IDs in the DOM should be unique. If you have multiple elements with the same id, I recommend changing them to classes. Then run your each function on the classes. Then you could do your javascript as follows:

```
$('#showoffline').click(function(){
  $.each($('.offlineestreams'), function(){
    $(this).css({'display': 'block'});
  });
});
```

Also update your HTML:

```
<div class="offlineestreams" style="display:none;">Something here</div>
<div class="offlineestreams" style="display:none;">Something here</div>
```